# Xamarin Forms media player -Full screen option (android)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi all I developed xamarin media player by help of this link its working perfectly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/ but I want to know  how can I add a fullscreen icon and make it work in Xamarin video player . please Help
[image]

Comment: It that renderer using a native video lib. or is it webview-based?

Comment: using a native video librery (VideoPlayerRenderer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom renderer refer to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/502)

To make the custom renderer work, I made some modification on the code:

First, replace the video renderer in your Android project with the custom video renderer, then move code in init method into VideoRenderer construcor and delete the init method, change the _context variable to Context and remove static:

```
Context _context;
double deviceWidth;
double deviceHeight;
```

then, use _context.GetActivity().RequestedOrientation instead of _context.RequestedOrientation in related method.

At last, icons need to be added to resource/drawable in Android, you can find the icon in the github issue link.

To make it full screen, need to hide extra UIs like:

```
var uiOpts = SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable 
                | SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen 
                | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation 
                | SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar
                | SystemUiFlags.Immersive
                | SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation
                | SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;

window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOpts;
```

and when exit full screen, clear the flags accordingly, here's a [google doc for full screen](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i followed the code .. orientation of screen changes to landscape but video player not captures the full screen . I need to make the video player to full-screen like normal other video player .Thanks

Comment: hi, you may need to hide extra System UIs with the updated code.

Comment: @NicoleLu-MSFT would you more explain your responce?